# Consolidate Code and Neaten Up in Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dataset in Google Sheets with a script below. I want to be able to neaten this up and consolidate the number of lines of code, specifically all the sheet.getRange statements

```
      sheet.appendRow([
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,5).getValue(),
      number+1,
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,7).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,8).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,9).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,10).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,11).getValue(),
      newDate,
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,13).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,14).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,15).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,16).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,17).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,18).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,19).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,20).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,21).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,22).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,23).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,24).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,25).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,26).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,27).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,28).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,29).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,30).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,31).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,32).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,33).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,34).getValue(),
      sheet.getRange(selectedRow,35).getValue()
      ]);
  }
```

If you could show me the code on how to reduce this it would be appreciated!

Comment: You would benefit from a careful reading of best practices in the support section of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I can see there is a pattern on your execution, therefore you don't have to write all the `getvalue()` since most of them is directly obtain from the range value without editing.

`GetValues()` is faster method to update all the value at once and you can change some of the value in the array by referring to its relevant position. At last, `appendrow` required `1D array` therefore you need to convert it using `array.flat()`:

**Code enhancement:**

```
 function app1() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var range1 = sheet.getRange(selectedRow,1,1,35).getValues();
      var number = 20;
    
      range1[0][0] = '';
      range1[0][1] = '';
      range1[0][2] = '';
      range1[0][3] = '';
      range1[0][5] = number + 1;
      range1[0][11] = new Date();
    
      sheet.appendRow(range1.flat());
    }
```